# Persistant profile avatar images like whatsapp even without internet

Tags: react-native

I am making a messaging app using React native and django for the back end. What I can't figure it out is how to make the Image persistant, like the profile avatar image of whatsapp or messenger show up even if there's not internet. I thought that the profile avatar images are saved in the device. But I didn't found any profile images in the device. How does these apps persist the image and how can I achieve the same using React native?

Comment: Not an answer, but search for how to download and store in Android.  You either have to provide avatars in the apk, or if you let them use photo, you'll need to check for, and fetch it from the DB.  Then you have to store it.  Sorry I'm not much help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to cache all avatars in the app forever. The easiest way is on server side to send back http cache control headers so that the app doesn't need to retrieve the image every time. You can set the cache time to a few days if the avatar url doesn't change for a user. If the url changes each time the avatar is updated, and from the app you can get the new url easily, then it's ok to set the cache time to forever. Old items will still be cleared because there is a limit on how much space the cache can use.